# Developer Salesforce docs doesn't seem to be indexed by Google/Bing?

Tags: apex, search, google

Did anyone else noticed that it's almost impossible to search anything on developer docs through google recently.

Previously search like this: "salesforce schema get describe" would return https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/ withing first few results, now however it's nowhere to be seen.

Comment: Noticed this last week also.

Comment: Faced that last month, was searching for visualforce standard components. After lot of search it popped Japanese version of Salesforce doc.

Comment: This is why the h&t portal exists, to look for salesforce related content